# Indent SymbolicC

Tags: code-generation, format

What is they shortest way to automatically indent SymbolicC at the Brackets `{` and `}`?

For example:

```
CProgram[
  CInclude["stdlib.h"],
  CInclude["constants.h"],
  CFunction["int", "value", {}, CBlock[{CReturn["valueDefine"]}]]
  ] // ToCCodeString
```

should give

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "constants.h"

int value()
{
    return valueDefine;
}
```

Comment: Voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Use

```
ToCCodeString[..., "Indent" -> 1]
```

I found this by checking `Options[ToCCodeString]`.  The `"Indent"` option appears to control the number of tabs that will be used for indenting.